# What is the simplest way to load language keys to a view in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

I'm using codeigniter and I'm building a multilingual site, so I use Language class like this:

```
$this->lang->load('index', 'english');
```

Then, in the controller, to load all the data into my view I do this:

```
$data["var1"] = $this->lang->line('language_key1');
$data["var2"] = $this->lang->line('language_key2');
$data["var3"] = $this->lang->line('language_key3');
$data["var4"] = $this->lang->line('language_key4');
$data["var5"] = $this->lang->line('language_key5');
...
$this->load->view('index', $data);
```

The problem is that in some controllers I have to load more than 100 language keys, and I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this instead of language class you can use language helper.

[Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/language_helper.html) is you can see the documentation

In you view you can use this

```
<p><?php echo lang('language_key1')?></p>
```

Also if you want to use language class you can use it like this

```
$data['language'] = $this->lang->load('index', 'english',true);
```

Passing third parameter as true will return the array of language items. Then in the view you can use like this

```
echo $language['language_key1'];
```

Comment: Thanks! and another question: Is a good practice load the meta description and meta keywords in a language file and load it depending on the user language?

Comment: i am afraid i dont have any idea about this as i have never done it like this

Comment: In case somebody looking for the recent User Guide. Visit [CodeIgniter Language Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)

Answer (score 0):

CI has `lang()` function in `system/language_helper.php`. And it uses directly in your template.

```
 <a href="#" class="slct"><?php lang('s_no') ?></a>
```

OR

```
<input type="submit" class="bigButton" value="<?php lang('lang_continue') ?>" />
```

More http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/language_helper.html